# Images sent with Mandrill not displaying

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, localhost, mandrill

I'm trying to include an image in an email sent with Mandrill from a Meteor site. When testing the site on my localhost, I tried sending the email to make sure everything was displaying correctly, but the image was not loading. Here's what I've done so far:

In my Mandrill template, I have `<img src="*|MYIMAGESOURCE|*" alt="some alt text">`.

Im my Meteor code I have:

```
Meteor.Mandrill.sendTemplate({
    ...
    "message" : {
        "global_merge_vars" : [{
          "name" : "myimagesource",
          "content" : Meteor.absoluteUrl("myimage.png", {"replaceLocalhost" : true})
        }],
        ...
      }
    ...
)};
```

I have tried both with and without `replaceLocalhost` and a couple other variations on the value of `"content"`. I am receiving the email, but images are replaced by white box with a question mark. When I inspect element on them their `src` attribute is something like `src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/[random letters and numbers]#http://local.mywebsite.com:3000/myimage.png"`.

What do I need to do to get the images to load correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the image exists somewhere on a publicly accessible server in order for this to work as you're expecting.

If I understand correctly, you're doing the following:

1. Working on a Meteor instance on your localhost (your URL looks like `http://localhost:3000/some-path`)
2. You call the Mandrill API to send an email, including a locally-hosted image file as the URL (the file is accessible on your local machine e.g. you have it in `/public/images/file-name.png`)
3. You ask Meteor to create an absolute URL to the image (using `Meteor.absoluteUrl()` but Meteor is only creating the link to the image on your local filesystem.
4. Mandrill sends the email, and when the recipient opens it, they see a cached version of the image (GMail catches images and caches them on a Google server, hence the `https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/` prefix for your image.
5. Since your image only exists on your local filesystem, it won't be accessible in the location which the email is telling the HTML to look for it.

### Suggested fix

If you need to run this test locally, you could use a publicly-accessible image instead of your local one (e.g. use http://imgur.com/ to host a dummy image and then use `"content": "http://i.imgur.com/WBFQlsJ.png"` in your Mandrill call.

Alternatively, deploy your app to test it e.g. `meteor deploy mysite.meteor.com` since the image will bew available publicly this way.